# Percentage based stop in pine script using non-traditional charts

Tags: python, pine-script

I created a good, simple, working strategy in pine script using renko signals executed on a traditional chart. In order to limit drawdown I am trying to add a percentage based stop. After reading an article on kodify I attempted to add the code but no go. Getting undeclared identifier error on lines 24/25 and 33/35, the "`long/shortLossPerc`" and the "`long/shortStopPrice`". Either there is an error in my code or something else is going on. Could be because the article I read referenced version 3 instead of version 4? Could be a syntax error or could it be because I am referencing my price data for signals from renko chart but executing at real time traditional chart prices. Any feedback appreciated thanks.

```
//@version=4
strategy("DC", overlay=true) //, resolution="", default_quantity_value=1)
//startDate = input(title="Start Date", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
//startMonth = input(title="Start Month", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1, maxval=12)
//startYear = input(title="Start Year", type=input.integer, defval=2019, minval=2000, maxval=2100)
//endDate = input(title="End Date", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
//endMonth = input(title="End Month", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1, maxval=12)
//endYear = input(title="End Year", type=input.integer, defval=2020, minval=2000, maxval=2100)
//t = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
//realC = security(t, timeframe.period, close)
//plot(realC)
length = input(1, minval=1)
lower = lowest(length)
upper = highest(length)
basis = avg(upper, lower)
//plot(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6A00)
//u = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#0094FF)
//l = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#0094FF)
//fill(u, l, color=#0094FF, transp=95, title="Background")
longLossPerc = input(title="Long Stop Loss (%)", 
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01
shortLossPerc = input(title="Short Stop Loss (%)", 
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01
longStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1- longLossPerc)
shortStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + shortLossPerc)
longCondition = security(renko(syminfo.tickerid, "Traditional", 200), timeframe.period, rising(basis, 2))
shortCondition = security(renko(syminfo.tickerid, "Traditional", 200), timeframe.period, falling(basis, 2))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="LS", stop=longStopPrice)
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="SS", stop=shortStopPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed code/syntax to

```
stopPer = input(1.0, title="Stop Loss %", type=input.float) / 100
longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPer)
shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopPer)
if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit(id="Close Long", stop=longStop)
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit(id="Close Short", stop=shortStop)
```

Works great. Perhaps there were some differences in the coding between version 3 and 4 I was unaware of. This code is much simpler than what I tried originally. Also you can reduce larger losses by adding,

```
process_orders_on_close=true
```

in your "strategy" line. This way your stop loss is added immediately once you enter a position rather than the close of the candle that you entered on. Hope this info helps.